# Bootstrap row horizontal alignments for div not working properly in small & medium screen resolutions

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

Login page with captcha and refresh captcha is not showing in the same line on small and medium screen resolutions. Please help. I have pasted my code here:

//Problem occurs at this point

```
 <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-2 ">        
    <div class = "form-group reload_div">
    <?php echo $captcha; ?>                
    </div>        
    </div>    
    <div class="col-sm-1 hr"  >           
    <div class = "form-group">                
    <i class="fa fa-refresh refresh-captcha "  aria-hidden="true" style="font-size: 25px;"></i>
    </div>        
    </div>   
    </div>
```

Problem occurs at this point ////

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that there is 12 logical columns per row in bootstrap not 3. sm-2 + sm-1 = 3. So the solution is ex. sm-10 sm-2.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 bg-primary captcha">
     <img src="https://placehold.it/150x100">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-9 hr bg-info">
      <div class="form-group">
        <i class="fa fa-refresh refresh-captcha " aria-hidden="true" style="font-size: 25px;"></i>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.captcha { min-width: 150px; }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/kvuzpsjL/28/

Comment: Thanks alexqc & neophyte for the response. I have tried with ur code. But captcha  text and refresh captcha are lying far apart from each other. In small screen size also, alignment is not correct.

Comment: Hi, I don't know what is the size of your captcha, so I've reserwerd 10 columns of space for it. Just adjust the amount of needed space, try with col-sm-3 col-sm-9 or col-sm-5 col-sm-7 and keep the total of 12 per row - this was real problem.

Comment: Thanks alexqc. I had given col-sm-2 col-sm-10. It is working fine with 1240&654 screen size. But below this screen size( like 800*1280) captcha text is overlapping refresh captcha and we can't see refresh captcha image. It is a responsive form.